# Question in debugging my list data structure in radix sort

Tags: c, algorithm

So here is my C radix sort program that went wrong, and I figured out it failed because I didn't clear the buckets before each round of radix sort and then actually successfully fixed it.

But, I don't know the details of the program's going wrong (or should I care?), why the `next` value (`(Position) 0x55550000007d`) is not `(struct Node *) 0x555555757270` (which is the value of `First(buckets[i])`) or `0x0` (which is the empty `Node` follows `First(buckets[i]`) when `e` is `1` and `i` is `5`, which leads to `Segmentation Fault` because I can't access `0x55550000007d` (according to `gdb`).

What happened?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "clib/list.h"

void create_buckets(List buckets[], int size);

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[10] = { 64, 8, 216, 512, 27, 729, 0, 1, 343, 125 };

    List buckets[10];
    int i = 0;

    create_buckets(buckets, sizeof (buckets) / sizeof (buckets[0]));
    int e = 0; // number of digits
    for (e = 0; e < 3; e++) {

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int number = numbers[i];
            int bucket_no = number / (int) pow(10, e) % 10;
            Insert(number, buckets[bucket_no], Last(buckets[bucket_no]));
        }

        int k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Position next = First(buckets[i]);
            while (next) {
                /*
                if (k >= 10) {
                    printf("something went wrong.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                */
                numbers[k++] = Retrieve(next);

                printf("e: %d, i: %d\n", e, i);

                /*
                if (e == 1 && i == 5) {
                    printf("where the debugger says something went wrong.\n");
                }
                */
                next = Advance(next);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("after sorting:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void create_buckets(List buckets[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        buckets[i] = MakeEmpty();
    }
}
```

Here is my `list.h` and `list.c` files:

list.h:

```
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_

struct Node;
typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode List;
typedef PtrToNode Position;
typedef int ElementType;

List MakeEmpty(void);
int IsEmpty(List L);
int IsLast(Position P, List L);
Position Find(ElementType X, List L);
void Delete(ElementType X, List L);
Position FindPrevious(ElementType X, List L);
void Insert(ElementType X, List L, Position P);
void DeleteList(List L);
Position Header(List L);
Position First(List L);
Position Last(List L);
Position Advance(Position P);
ElementType Retrieve(Position P);

#endif
```

list.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

struct Node {
    ElementType Element;
    Position next;
};

void *my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *m = malloc(size);

    if (!m) {
        printf("failed to allocate memory.\n");
    }

    return m;
}

List MakeEmpty(void)
{
    List l = my_malloc(sizeof (struct Node));

    l->next = NULL;

    return l;
}

int IsEmpty(List L)
{
    return L->next == NULL;
}

int IsLast(Position P, List L)
{
    return L->next != NULL && P->next == NULL;
}

Position Find(ElementType X, List L)
{
    Position o;

    for (o = L->next; o != NULL; o = o->next) {
        if (o->Element == X) {
            return o;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void Delete(ElementType X, List L)
{
    Position pre, tmp;

    pre = FindPrevious(X, L);
    if (!IsLast(pre, L)) {
        tmp = pre->next;
        pre->next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

Position FindPrevious(ElementType X, List L)
{
    Position pre, cur;

    pre = L;
    cur = L->next;

    for (; cur != NULL; pre = cur, cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->Element == X) {
            return pre;
        }
    }

    return pre;
}

void Insert(ElementType X, List L, Position P)
{
    Position new = my_malloc(sizeof (struct Node));

    if (!IsEmpty(L) && !P) {
        printf("insert behind a empty node in a non-empty list.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    new->Element = X;
    new->next = NULL;

    if (IsEmpty(L)) {
        L->next = new;
    } else {
        new->next  = P->next;
        P->next = new;
    }
}

void DeleteList(List L)
{
    Position prev = L;
    Position cur = L->next;

    while (!cur) {
        free(prev);
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

Position Header(List L)
{
    return L;
}

Position First(List L)
{
    return L->next;
}

ElementType Retrieve(Position P)
{
    return P->Element;
}

Position Advance(Position p)
{
    if (p) {
        return p->next;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

Position Last(List L)
{
    if (IsEmpty(L)) {
        return Header(L);
    }

    Position last = First(L);

    while (Advance(last)) {
        last = Advance(last);
    }

    return last;
}
```

Comment: `(int) pow(10, e)` is prone to inexactness troubles.  Could use `lround(pow(10, e))`, but better to refactor code - do not use FP functions for an integer problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. (it took me a few searches and guesses to know FP == floating point :-p